# Adding window.addEventListener to Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm working with the Google reCAPTCHA element and added it as an iframe to a Lightning component (this iframe method is to get around CSP issues in Salesforce):

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">

    <iframe src="/apex/Recaptcha" height="95px" width="304px" frameborder="0" title="Recaptcha checkbox" />

</aura:component>
```

I'd like to add `window.addEventListener` in the `doInit` so that I can determine if the reCAPTCHA checkbox has been checked. So I've done the following in the component's render.js file:

```
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();

    // Origin from where message will come to Lightning component, i.e., Visualforce page origin
    let vfOrigin = "https://power-efficiency-8776-dev-ed--c.visualforce.com";

    window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
        if (event.origin !== vfOrigin) {
            // Not the expected origin; Reject the message!
            return;
        }
        if (event.data === "Unlock") {
            alert("yay, it was checked!");
        }
    }, false);
},
```

However, this `window.addEventListener` section isn't being hit. I originally had the code in `doInit` in the controller, but that didn't work either. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: did you try addEventListener section in  afterRender: function(component,helper){
    this.superAfterRender();} function instead of doInit?

Comment: @sdandamud1 no I didn't. You mean to add that to the Render.js of the component and insert addEventListener after superAfterRender()?

Comment: yes, at the time of controller init function, the dom is not ready and your components have not rendered yet

Comment: @sdandamud1 thanks! I tried that with no different results, but I'm going to update my question with those steps.

Comment: instead of putting code in afterRender put code in init in controller. It will work.

Comment: @DhanikLalSahni I originally had it in `doInit` in the controller but it wasn't working.

Comment: @MattSmith  are you trying bind "message" eventhandler to window? in question.